# AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener

Tags: java, android

Встретил такой Андроид код:

```
/**
 * This listener gets triggered whenever the audio focus changes
 * (i.e., we gain or lose audio focus because of another app or device).
 */
private AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener mOnAudioFocusChangeListener = new AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAudioFocusChange(int focusChange) {
        if (focusChange == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT ||
                focusChange == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT_CAN_DUCK) {
            // The AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT case means that we've lost audio focus for a
            // short amount of time. The AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT_CAN_DUCK case means that
            // our app is allowed to continue playing sound but at a lower volume. We'll treat
            // both cases the same way because our app is playing short sound files.

            // Pause playback and reset player to the start of the file. That way, we can
            // play the word from the beginning when we resume playback.
            mMediaPlayer.pause();
            mMediaPlayer.seekTo(0);
        } else if (focusChange == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN) {
            // The AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN case means we have regained focus and can resume playback.
            mMediaPlayer.start();
        } else if (focusChange == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS) {
            // The AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS case means we've lost audio focus and
            // Stop playback and clean up resources
            releaseMediaPlayer();
        }
    }
};
```

прогуглил что это интерфейс, но не могу понять как он работает. Вроде же нельзя создавать объект интерфейса с помощью **new**, и еще почему в конце стоит точка с запятой после фигурной скобки ? )))
И еще, переопределенный метод автоматически вызывается ?? Если да, то почему, как это работает никак не пойму ?!

Comment: загугли "java анонимные классы"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это интерфейс переменная (Interface variable).

Простой пример:

```
TextView tv = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.hello_world);
//Interface
View.OnClickListener m_click_itf = new View.OnClickListener() {
              @Override
              public void onClick(View v) {
                      // TODO Auto-generated method stub

              }
}; // сам по себе работать не будет
tv.setOnClickListener(m_click_itf);
```

[Источник](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2014/01/android-event-handling/)

---

На счет точки с запятой, ну вот положено так у интерфейсов, смиритесь.

> Вроде же нельзя создавать объект интерфейса с помощью new

где Вы такое вычитали?

Теперь, непосредственно, перейдём к вашему коду. Это также ещё называют `callback`'ом. Он не работает сам по себе. На данный `callback` необходимо подписаться, а также обязательно отписываться в `onStop`, дабы избежать утечки памяти.

Если бы вы посмотрели код дальше, ну или использовали `ctrl+f` и в били бы туда `mOnAudioFocusChangeListener`, то увидели бы что на данный интерфейс подписываются таким способом, непосредственно, в `onCreate`:

```
// Request audio focus so in order to play the audio file. The app needs to play a
// short audio file, so we will request audio focus with a short amount of time
// with AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT.
int result = mAudioManager.requestAudioFocus(mOnAudioFocusChangeListener, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT);
```

А также отписываются от этого, непосредственно, в `onStop`:

```
// Regardless of whether or not we were granted audio focus, abandon it. This also
// unregisters the AudioFocusChangeListener so we don't get anymore callbacks.
mAudioManager.abandonAudioFocus(mOnAudioFocusChangeListener);
```

---

`@Override` - это переопределение метода под ваши нужды.

Например:

Изначально данный метод используется для возращения на предыдущую активити или закрытие приложения, не суть.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
     super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Вы можете изменить его под свои нужды:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Hello World!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

И теперь вместо выхода из активити или перехода, выведется сообщение с информацией.

Comment: Спасибо,понял!!

Comment: А что насчет @Override метода он автоматически вызывется ?? И почему так ?

Comment: @rarity- обновил ответ

Comment: ну да это я понял, я имел ввиду, например когда мы устанавливаем обработчик событий OnClickListenre допустим на кнопку переопределяем метод OnClick, и вот этот метод вызывается автоматически при нажатии на кнопку? вот я хотел узнать это как работает ?

Comment: @rarity-  ну да, каждый раз когда, вы будите нажимать на кнопку, будут выполнятся те или иные действия, которые прописаны внутри onClick()

Comment: )) ну допутим если я напишу в OnClickListener кроме метода онКлик другой свой метод он же не будет автоматически вызываться ? Вот, я имел ввиду как это сделано что он вызывается автоматически ?

Comment: @rarity- ну, OnClickListener может использовать только onClick() метод, а вот уже внутри него onClick() можете делать все что душе угодно

Comment: Ну смотрите, я знаю что при создании экземпляра класса, методы которые были обьявлены в конструкторе этогр класса автоматически вызываются так ведь?? А как это работает с обработчиком событий? Это ведь интерфейс я просто  пока плохо  разбираюсь в них